# mongoose conditions querying the right way with find and populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node Js so I am having difficulties to query with find function and populate with conditions.

Here is the schema :

```
    var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
ips: [{
    ip: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ip'
    }
}]});
```

IP schema :

```
var IpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
ip: String,
objects: [{
    object:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'object'
    }
}]});
```

Here is the Object Schema :

```
var ObjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
a: String,
b: String});
```

Here is the query :

```
DB.findOne({name: nameReq})
.populate(
{
    path: 'ips.ip',model: 'Ip',
    populate: 
            {
                path: 'objects.object',model: 'Object'
            }
})
.exec(function(err,obj) 
{
    if(err) return callback(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t"));
})
```

Now the above query return all the results with the name "nameReq" in addition to that i want to add more condition but for the IP schema section and to the Object schema section .

How can i do so ?

Thanks

Comment: please add examples of documents and expected results

Comment: You can use `match` to filter results. look for **Query conditions and other options** here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks Tom 

Using match did work .

Comment: no problem, a "thumbs up" on my comment would be appreciated :)

Comment: But query result return all the Find function and populate only the match condition which results in some null's on query results : 
Good results like this : 

{ "_id": "57d15910673267a818b6dba9", "XXX": "XXXX", "__v": 0, "ips": [ { "ip": { "_id": "57d15910673267a818b6dba4", "ip": "1.1.1.1", "__v": 0

With bad results like this : 

 { "ip": null, "_id": "57d15a2b16d660d4037cccd1" }, 

Is their any way to remove the array object that dosent answer the population condition ?